# Best URL structure approach

Tags: php, url, design-patterns, symfony

In my application I have the following url structure where by, things like the profile page will load data based on the logged in user if no username is provided and load a different users profile if one is e.g.

**/profile** - loads logged in users profile

**/profile/eddy** - loads eddys profile

However things have gotten a little messy take for example a note.

**/note/view/note-book-slug/note-slug**

I can either follow the same pattern as the profile page and have an optional last parameter for username otherwise loading the logged in user data e.g.

**/note/view/note-book-slug/note-slug** - Find a logged in users note

**/note/view/note-book-slug/note-slug/eddy** - Find a note owned by eddy

But that does not look like it makes much sense, so my thoughts would be to require the username as the first param for all resources regardless of whether we want a logged in users data or someone else's.

Are my thoughts correct / the best approach, or am I looking at this in the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thoughts are correct. I would do it in the same way. Point out that URL to be nice needs only to be short and has parameters friendly to search engine. Your concept has that features and it is the most important.

Comment: thanks for confirming

Comment: Of course this only works if username is your only optional parameter.  You could consider /note/view/note-book-slug/note-slug?user=eddy,group=students